# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name ORACLE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I tried to execute the following oracle query using JdbcTemplate in Java:

```
select RESOURCE_ID 
from REPRO_PRINTING_JOB 
where (USER_ID=? and PRINTING_CENTER_ID=?) 
group by RESOURCE_ID 
union all 
select RESOURCE_ID 
from REPRO_PRINTING_JOB_OLD 
where (USER_ID=? and PRINTING_CENTER_ID=? and STATE='CM') 
group by RESOURCE_ID
```

The query is working perfectly in oracle query browser but its not working during the execution in java. What could be the source of this problem? I´ve heard something about Jdbc cannot handle case sensitive. Is this true?

ADDED JAVA CODE(CORRECTED) :
I call the query using getStatement() which retrieves the query from external source(a properties file) as belows :

```
   public List<PrintingJob> getPrintingJobsByCreatedUserId(String createdUserId, String userId) {
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("getReportItemsByUserId(" + createdUserId + "," + userId + ")");
    }
    try {               
        System.out.println("getPrintingJobsByResourceId : createdUserId :"+createdUserId+",userId : "+userId);
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(getStatement("gen.report.userid"),                       
                new Object[]{createdUserId, userId, createdUserId, userId},                     
                new PrintingJobMapper());           
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {              
            log.error("Error executing query: " + ex.getClass() + ":" + ex.getMessage());               
            return null;            
        }       
}
```

Comment: and how you are writing this in Java?

Comment: Are you sure the query is read correctly, since you're reading it from a properties file?

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure because if it didn't read the statement correctly, java would have thrown NoSuchElementException where the related key hasn't been found.

Comment: please print the statement as read from the property file and the complete exception and show us the result.

Comment: Are you sure the exception occurs in the select and not in the rowmapper?

Comment: @tom I've checked the mapper and it returned all the fields correctly

Comment: PRINTING_CENTER_ID and USER_ID are numbers, right ?

Comment: @Best did u get the solution?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting this error is because it is an error from the JDBC driver or java.sql API, not from the database. Note the lack of ORA-XXXXX in the exception message. If it contained that, then it would be related to syntax, invalid name or something that would go wrong on the database server side.

SQLExceptions are thrown in java for anything related to the SQL api, not just from errors that occur when statements are sent over the connection... In this case, it is likely that the query in fact ran correctly but the result set API is giving you errors (rs.getLong("blah"), where column "blah" doesn't exist in your select) is causing problems.